# How find the fractional part of $5^{200}$ divided by $8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility, binomial-theorem, fractional-part

Finding the fractional part of $\frac{5^{200}}{8}$.

I've had this problem given to me (we're learning the Binomial Theorem and all.) So obviously I thought I'd apply the binomial theorem to it, somehow.

I've tried writing $5$ as $8-3$, and expanding the numerator, so that all but one term would be divisible by $8$, (the one term being the constant term.) and hence the fractional part would only (possibly) arise from the constant term being divided by 8. But apparently this is not working because the constant term itself is of the order of magnitude of the original numerator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to write $5=4+1$? It is often convenient to have $1$ in the binomial formula.

Comment: Write it as $(1+24)^{100}$

Comment: I think that perhaps you didn't take the problem far enough. I think that you ended up with the constant term $(-3)^{200}$. Just rewrite this as $9^{100} = (8+1)^{100}$

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8 \implies 5^{200} = (5^2)^{100} \equiv 1^{100} \pmod8 \equiv 1 \pmod8$$
We hence have
$$5^{200} = 8M + 1 \implies \dfrac{5^{200}}8 = M + \dfrac18$$
where $M \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence, the fractional part is $1/8$.

---

**EDIT** Another equivalent way is to write $5^{200}$ as $(4+1)^{200}$ and then use binomial theorem, i.e.,
$$5^{200} = (1+4)^{200} = \sum_{k=0}^{200} \dbinom{200}k 4^k$$
Note that $8$ divides $4^k$ for all $k \geq 2$. Hence, we have
$$5^{200} = 8N + \dbinom{200}1 4^1 + \dbinom{200}{0} 4^0 =8N + 800 + 1 = 8M+1$$
We hence have
$$5^{200} = 8M + 1 \implies \dfrac{5^{200}}8 = M + \dfrac18$$
where $M \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence, the fractional part is $1/8$.

Comment: The op won't be able to understand Modular arithmetic , as I am from India as well. This isn't in our course at high school.

Comment: @Mann I am from India as well and we learnt modular arithmetic in our 11th standard for Olympiads.

Comment: For Olympiads, you see, not in standard course.

Comment: I did learn modular arithmetic on my own, so its okay! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mann There is nothing called as standard. Every one has his/her own standard.

Comment: I am not calling for that, but i mean not in standard Indian courses of +1 and +2. It's not the prescribed syllabus. So , you usually have to assume the op usually doesn't know modular arithmetic and i have seen many answers like that. Anyway sorry. And glad you learnt it , @hritik.

Comment: @Mann Nothing to be sorry about. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, @user17762!

Answer (score 2):

$5^2\equiv 1\mod 8$, hence $5^{200}\equiv 1\mod 8$. Thus the fractional part is $\dfrac18=0·125$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a answer without modular arithmetic if you require it,

$5^{200}=25^{100}=(1+24)^{100}$

Now expanding binomially,

$1+^{100}C_1*24+^{100}C_2*(24)^2+(O)$

Now simply divide by 8 and you got the fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove by induction that the fractional part of $5^{2n}$ is $\frac18$.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$5^2=8\cdot3+1$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$5^{2n}=8k+1$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$5^{2(n+1)}=$

$5^{2n+2}=$

$5^{2n}\cdot5^2=$

$\color{red}{5^{2n}}\cdot25=$

$(\color{red}{8k+1})\cdot25$

$200k+25=$

$200k+24+1=$

$8(25k+3)+1$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: Woah, I really like this proof.

Comment: @HritikNarayan: Thanks :)